# Unity UI Dropdown options from folder

Tags: c#, user-interface, drop-down-menu, unity-game-engine

I have a dropdown and I want to read in all the files in a certain folder and then put them as options for the dropdown.

```
if (obj.name.Contains("AudioSphere"))
{
    // Finding the dropdown menu with tag "audioDropdown"
    Dropdown dropdown = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("audioDropdown");

    // Finding all the music files
    FileInfo[] options = getAudioFiles();

    // add Options to the dropdown from list
    for (FileInfo data : options) {
        dropdown.AddOptions(new Dropdown.OptionData(data.Name));

    }
}
```

I met a lot of errors and I need some help with them. I'm new to all these UI things in Unity.

```
private FileInfo[] getAudioFiles()
{
    String path = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/Audiofiles";

    // How to check if exists?

    DirectoryInfo audioFolder = new DirectoryInfo(@path);
   FileInfo[] audioFiles = audioFolder.GetFiles();


    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is answered here:

[LINK to answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1175285/unity-ui-dropdown-options-from-folder.html#answer-1175714)